# Is there a way to be notified when objects in an IndexedDB ObjectStore gets inserted/updated/deleted?

Tags: html, indexeddb

I only see an event that fires on schema updates, is there any notification mechanism for data changes in IndexedDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At least, it's not part of the spec. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2013JanMar/thread.html#msg246 for discussion.